# Pyspark celery task : toPandas() throwing Pickling error

Tags: python, django, apache-spark, pyspark, celery

I have a web application to run long running tasks in pyspark. I am using Django, and Celery to run the tasks asynchronously.

I have a piece of code that works great when I execute it in the console. But I am getting quite some errors when I run it through the celery task. 
Firstly, my udf's don't work for some reason. I put it in a try-except block and it always goes in to the except block.

```
try:
    func = udf(lambda x: parse(x), DateType())
    spark_data_frame = spark_data_frame.withColumn('date_format', func(col(date_name)))
except:
    raise ValueError("No valid date format found.")
```

The error :

```
[2018-04-05 07:47:37,223: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task algorithms.tasks.outlier_algorithm[afbda586-0929-4d51-87f1-d612cbdb4c5e] raised unexpected: Py4JError('An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction. Trace:\npy4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction([class java.lang.String, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType$, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:235)\n\tat py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)\n\tat py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n\n',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/eugenie/algorithms/tasks.py", line 68, in outlier_algorithm
    spark_data_frame = spark_data_frame.withColumn('date_format', func(col(date_name)))
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 179, in wrapper
    return self(*args)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 157, in __call__
    judf = self._judf
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 141, in _judf
    self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf()
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 153, in _create_judf
    self._name, wrapped_func, jdt, self.evalType, self.deterministic)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1428, in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 324, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction([class java.lang.String, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType$, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:235)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Further, I am using toPandas() to convert the dataframe and run some pandas function on it but it throws the following error:

```
[2018-04-05 07:46:29,701: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task algorithms.tasks.outlier_algorithm[ec267a9b-b482-492d-8404-70b489fbbfe7] raised unexpected: Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o224.get.\n', 'JavaObject id=o225')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/eugenie/algorithms/tasks.py", line 146, in outlier_algorithm
    data_frame_new = data_frame_1.toPandas()
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1937, in toPandas
    if self.sql_ctx.getConf("spark.sql.execution.pandas.respectSessionTimeZone").lower() \
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 142, in getConf
    return self.sparkSession.conf.get(key, defaultValue)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/conf.py", line 46, in get
    return self._jconf.get(key)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: ('An error occurred while calling o224.get.\n', 'JavaObject id=o225')
[2018-04-05 07:46:29,706: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: <MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '"(1, <ExceptionInfo: Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o224.get.\\n', 'JavaObject id=o225')>, None)"'. Reason: ''PicklingError("Can\'t pickle <class \'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError\'>: it\'s not the same object as py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError",)''.>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 362, in workloop
    put((READY, (job, i, result, inqW_fd)))
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/billiard/queues.py", line 366, in put
    self.send_payload(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.4/site-packages/billiard/reduction.py", line 56, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
billiard.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '"(1, <ExceptionInfo: Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o224.get.\\n', 'JavaObject id=o225')>, None)"'. Reason: ''PicklingError("Can\'t pickle <class \'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError\'>: it\'s not the same object as py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError",)''.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. It was probably a pyspark 2.3 bug
I was using Pyspark 2.3.0 and for some reason it did not work well with Python 3.5.
I downgraded to Pyspark 2.1.2 and everything worked fine.

Comment: Im able to reproduce this with 2.3.1 too :/ There is another bug which does not allow me to use pyspark 2.1.2 ... so, im at a loss. Any progress in trying to fix the issue with pyspark 2.3.x ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and was having a hard time pinning it down. As it turns out this error can occur if the version of Spark you are running does not match the version of PySpark you are executing it with. In my case I am running Spark 2.2.3.4 and was trying to use PySpark 2.4.4. After I downgraded PySpark to 2.2.3 the problem went away. I ran into another problem caused by the code using functionality in PySpark that was added after 2.2.3, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is just not going to work. Spark uses complex state, including JVM state, which cannot be simply serialized and send to the worker. If you want to run your code asynchronously, use thread pool to submit jobs.

Comment: Actually I need progress updates too from these long running jobs. I'm reading up on thread pooling.